# Secuencia en C#

Tags: c#

Buen dia!
En mi tarea viene:

A continuación se le presenta una secuencia con 5 números enteros:   2,4,9,20,40,

a) Encuentre la secuencia que permita identificar el 6to numero entero y con la formula encontrada permita a un usuario visualizar la cantidad de números que el desee visualizar. por ejemplo si el usuario desea visualizar únicamente 3 números debería visualizar en pantalla: 2,4 y 9, por el contrario, si el usuario desea visualizar 7 numeros en pantalla, debería visualizar en pantalla 2,4,9,20,40,?,? (El ? son los que siguen).

```
for (i = 2; i <= tope; i = i + tope) {
    n1 = n1 * 10;
    n2 = n2 * 10;
    n3 = n3 * 10;
    Console.WriteLine(n1);
    Console.WriteLine(n2);
    Console.WriteLine(n3);
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: for (i = 2; i <= tope; i=i+tope)
                {
                    
                    n1 = n1 * 10;
                    n2 = n2 * 10;
                    n3 = n3 * 10;
                    Console.WriteLine(n1);
                    Console.WriteLine(n2);
                    Console.WriteLine(n3);
                }

Comment: Parece que la secuencia es incorrecta. Creo que la correcta es 2, 4, 9, 20, 43, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cualquier persona de la comunidad te puede ayudar, pero debes de agregar código en tu pregunta para que veamos que cosas has intentado.

Hice esta función (Tiene mucho tiempo que no entro en C# pero la lógica es la misma)

```
   void sucesion(tope) {
        total = 2;
        index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index <= tope; index++) {
            total = 2 * (total) + index;
            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias!, fue una muy acertada respuesta, lo que no entendía era a la hora de la sucesión, aunque no era exactamente lo que buscaba, me abriste la mente y funciono con unos cambios que apliqué, ¡Mil gracias en serio!

Comment: Cuando tengas tu solución, modifica tu pregunta y agrega el código, por si alguien mas tiene este problema.